# How to send Email using Mailgun and Laravel?

Tags: laravel, email, mailgun

I have a Contact page with a Contact Form on it. I'm using Laravel and Vue js. I've been sending test emails using Mailtrap on my localhost and everything works great.
After deploying my App to GoDaddy, I am now using Mailgun to send email. I removed these settings in my .env file:

```
#MAIL_MAILER=smtp
#MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
#MAIL_PORT=2525
#MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxx
#MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
#MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

And now I have only these settings in my .env file:

```
MAIL_MAILER=mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=highrjobs.com
MAILGUN_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I'm getting this error on Live Production site, after I click Submit, it says: `server error`.

I looked in storage/logs/laravel.log file and it gives me this error:
`prod.ERROR: Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.mailtrap.io:2525 (Connection refused) {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 0): Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.mailtrap.io:2525 (Connection refused) at /home/ymq6es2sf6km/highrjobs/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:269)`

Why is it still trying to connect to mailtrap via smtp, I'm overriding these settings in my .env file as listed above.

Here is my config.php file:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Mailer
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default mailer that is used to send any email
    | messages sent by your application. Alternative mailers may be setup
    | and used as needed; however, this mailer will be used by default.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'mailgun'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mailer Configurations
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure all of the mailers used by your application plus
    | their respective settings. Several examples have been configured for
    | you and you are free to add your own as your application requires.
    |
    | Laravel supports a variety of mail "transport" drivers to be used while
    | sending an e-mail. You will specify which one you are using for your
    | mailers below. You are free to add additional mailers as required.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "ses",
    |            "postmark", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'test@test.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Highr Jobs Inc. - Support Team'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

and I added this in services.php:

```
'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
        'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT', 'api.mailgun.net'),
    ],
```

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Did you check out config/mail.php settings?

Comment: I updated my question, please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in my code was good. I ran these two commands and now it works!

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

```
php artisan config:cache
```